# Ruby modify elements of nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a RoR application in which at some point I recieve some params in the form of a hash. There's a field `amount` repeated within the hash. I want the value of these fields inverted.
This is an example of the nested hash:

```
{"name"=>"asdasd", "rate_type"=>"DependantRate",
 "category_rate_requests_attributes"=>{
   "0"=>{
     "date_from"=>"2016-08-03", "date_to"=>"2016-08-03",
     "room_category_rates_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{"r_id"=>"7", "amount"=>"5"},
       "1"=>{"r_id"=>"98", "amount"=>"15"},
       "2"=>{"r_id"=>"3", "amount"=>"25"},
       "3"=>{"r_id"=>"1", "amount"=>"35"},
       "4"=>{"r_id"=>"115", "amount"=>"45"},
       "5"=>{"r_id"=>"116", "amount"=>"55"},
       "6"=>{"r_id"=>"117", "amount"=>"65"}
     }
   },
   "1"=>{
     "date_from"=>"2016-08-05", "date_to"=>"2016-08-07",
     "room_category_rates_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{"r_id"=>"7", "amount"=>"3"},
       "1"=>{"r_id"=>"98", "amount"=>"13"},
       "2"=>{"r_id"=>"3", "amount"=>"23"},
       "3"=>{"r_id"=>"1", "amount"=>"33"},
       "4"=>{"r_id"=>"115", "amount"=>"43"},
       "5"=>{"r_id"=>"116", "amount"=>"53"},
       "6"=>{"r_id"=>"117", "amount"=>"63"}
     }
   }
 }
}
```

And I want to obtain a new hash which has that `amount`field with the same values but negative, as in:

```
{"name"=>"asdasd", "rate_type"=>"DependantRate",
 "category_rate_requests_attributes"=>{
   "0"=>{
     "date_from"=>"2016-08-03", "date_to"=>"2016-08-03",
     "room_category_rates_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{"r_id"=>"7", "amount"=>-5},
       "1"=>{"r_id"=>"98", "amount"=>-15},
       "2"=>{"r_id"=>"3", "amount"=>-25},
       "3"=>{"r_id"=>"1", "amount"=>-35},
       "4"=>{"r_id"=>"115", "amount"=>-45},
       "5"=>{"r_id"=>"116", "amount"=>-55},
       "6"=>{"r_id"=>"117", "amount"=>-65}
     }
   },
   "1"=>{
     "date_from"=>"2016-08-05", "date_to"=>"2016-08-07",
     "room_category_rates_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{"r_id"=>"7", "amount"=>-3},
       "1"=>{"r_id"=>"98", "amount"=>-13},
       "2"=>{"r_id"=>"3", "amount"=>-23},
       "3"=>{"r_id"=>"1", "amount"=>-33},
       "4"=>{"r_id"=>"115", "amount"=>-43},
       "5"=>{"r_id"=>"116", "amount"=>-53},
       "6"=>{"r_id"=>"117", "amount"=>-63}
     }
   }
 }
}
```

(yes, the values are now numbers but it doesn't really matter if they are strings or numbers as long as they are negative).

This is what I've came up with:

```
rate_params[:category_rate_requests_attributes].try(:each) do |_key1, category_rate_request|
  category_rate_request[:room_category_rates_attributes].each do |_key2, room_category_rate|
    room_category_rate[:amount] = room_category_rate[:amount].to_i * -1
  end
end
```

But it's far from nice code.

Any suggestions on what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Your code seems quite straightforward. Not much you can do with a nested hash.
Since your task is pretty easy while i'd still go with you initial solution this would also work ;)

    new_hash = JSON.parse(old_hash.to_json.gsub(/("amount":")(\d+)(")/, '\1-\2\3'))

Comment: Please pare down examples to their bare essentials. For hashes, that means eliminating extraneous key-value pairs and shortening keys and values. Also, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object so that readers can refer to those variables in text and code without having to define them. Your entire hash could be, for example,  `h = { "name"=>"abc", attr1=>{ 123=>{ :month=>1, :day=>2 }, attr2=>{ "310"=>{"room"=>"7", "amount"=>15}, "314"=>{"room"=>"98", "amount"=>25} } } }`. Among other things, readers will now be able to read your code without the need for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will do it shortly

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do with hashes but loop through them.

However, if you're guaranteed that the category_rate_requests hash will always be one element (arguments about whether that's a good idea aside), you can skip that loop with something like

```
rate_params["category_rate_requests_attributes"].values.first["room_category_rates_attributes"].each{|key, room_category_rate| room_category_rate["amount"] = room_category_rate["amount"].to_i * -1}
```

This assumes that hash is always the same structure, but if that's the case, you can grab `category_rate_requests_attributes` directly. Knowing it's always a one-element hash, use `values` to get an array of it's values, take the `first` (and only) element of that array, and loop through the resulting hash to invert the amounts.

I'm not sure it's any "nicer", but it's another path anyway.